# How to rewrite CSS selector rules?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make a daemon to combine multiples web pages into one.

My current idea is that give all pages an id and contain their body content in the div. For example, page A has these contents:

```
<html class="A">
  <body class="B">
    <div class="C">
```

We wrap them into the combination page, transfering the attrs of html and body tags into div:

```
<div id="item0001">
  <div id="item0001html" class="A">
    <div id="item0001body" class="B">
      <div class="C">
```

Now the work is to combine their css together. To achieve this, I want to replace all "html" and "body" element selectors into the corresponding id and prefix with the wrapper id. For example, ".mydiv {color: red;}" should become "#item0001 .mydiv {color: red;}"; "body span {color: red;}" should become "#item0001 #item0001body span {color: red;}".

However, the CSS rule is so complex that simple find-replace rule doesn't work. I have no idea to recognize the element selectors in a complex css rule. Is there a way or a framework to parse and rewrite the selectors of CSS?

(I'm using javascript to do this)

Comment: It seems like what you've got already will almost work. The most you'd change is the `html`, `head` and it's children, and `body` elements. The next thing you would need to change is to make sure there aren't duplicated `id` attributes. You could do this, by checking id uniqueness as you append html onto your result. If an id  was already used prepend it like you are with `html` and `body`.

Comment: the `<style scoped>/* here the specific rules or CSS file attached to this page inserted */ </style>` tag, inserted in each new wrapper would work, unfortunately, many browser do not properly understand/apply it. So, the first good idea, to parse each css file and add the id attribute in front each rules would do. But it  uses lot's of ressource/time to go through all of CSS found, it turns to be not such an efficient way. This could be treated ahead where each page already have an id on HTML or Body tag and where id already stands in front of CSS rules.

Comment: The correct solution would indeed be `<style scoped>`, but also indeed it has [no real browser support](http://caniuse.com/style-scoped). Then again, what you are doing is essentially re-inventing the age-old concept of an `iframe`, which begs the question: why not an `iframe`?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes iframe makes all pages separate and difficult for scripting. Also I don't know if there's a way to show each iframe with no scrolling, full width, and full height (as its content should expends)... If there's a solution, I'd like to consider it.

Comment: If the frames are on the same domain, or at least under your control up to the point of where you can inject a single JS file, it's a few lines of code to set up resize notifications with `PostMessage`, allowing you to sync the sizes. For third party content it's not practically feasible today.